# Unable to install Windows Server 2022 Host Key on 2012R2 KMS Service

Tags: windows, upgrade, keys, activation, kms

I have tried installing "Windows Srv 2022 DataCtr/Std KMS host key" on Windows Server 2012R2 KMS server, but apparently it is failing:

```
The following error has occurred. Please resolve the error and try again.


Description:

The Software Licensing Service reported that the product key is invalid.
```

I am sure the key is correct, and I have the host key of 2019 already installed. **I looked if there is an update to KMS on 2012R2 as the case has been for 2019, but apparently not yet**, if anyone has an idea on how to get this going on 2012R2, help appreciated :)

Comment: Not supported. 2016/2019 KMS only at this point.    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5003478-update-to-extend-kms-support-for-windows-server-2022-ltsc-5ae389ab-7650-46a7-ad53-bc7653684dfc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: I did upgrade the server from 2012R2 to 2022 after putting the question. yes this solves the issue. Thank you, put this as an anwer plz.

Comment: Mainstream support has already ended for 2012R2, so you should not expect such an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to a Microsoft representative today since we are about to renew our Microsoft products plan, and there are no plans for extending Key Management Service (KMS) on 2012R2 to support Windows Server 2022 activation (or the installation of the 2022 KMS host keys).

**As I mentioned earlier in the last comment, I was able to successfully upgrade the KMS server from 2012R2 to 2022 without any issues and installed the 2022 KMS host key. I also removed the 2019 KMS host key as it is no longer required.**

`Note`

I upgraded 47x 2012R2 servers during the last 10 days, I am stunned that all upgrades were successful, among which were servers for Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager, NPS, Certificate authority, Azure AD Sync, WDS, WSUS, KMS, and TFS.

It is also worth mentioning that I as able to install Sharepoint 2019 on Windows server 2022 and it has been running without any issues.

Hope this is useful for people planning to upgrade their setups.